# How can I get the value from the DB query?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Code below:

$data = DB::table('information')

->select(DB::raw('SUM(working) as working'))

->where('name', '=', 'ismael')

->get();

error_log($data);

it print: [{"working":"23"}]

how can I get the 23? without the "working"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use method `sum`:

```php
DB::table('information')->where('name', '=', 'ismael')->sum('working')
```

Or call the attribute:

```php
DB::table('information')->where('name', '=', 'ismael')->select(DB::raw('SUM(working) as working'))->first()->working
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = DB::table('information')
->select(DB::raw('SUM(working) as working'))
->where('name', '=', 'ismael')
->first()->working;
```